# How do I include 64 bit python with ArcGIS 10.4 install?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.4, 64bit, background-geoprocessing

I recently updated to 10.4 and was hoping the 64 bit python install was automatic, but apparently it isn't. I can't remember what I did in 10.3.x to get the 64 bit python. Does anyone know how to install it so that `C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.4` is included? Is it a separate download and install? All I have been able to find is [this link](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/67/metaid/2098) for 10.2.

---

In [this link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/executing-tools/64bit-background.htm) for 10.4, it says:

> Background Geoprocessing (64-bit) is available as a separate installation on top of ArcGIS for Desktop

But I can't find anywhere on that page that says how to go about the "separate installation"...

Comment: It can be downloaded from my.esri.com.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall If you want to post this as an answer I'll give you credit for it--

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The download for the 64 bit geoprocessing installation is not freely available. I found it in my.esri.com under My Organizations -> Downloads -> ArcGIS for Desktop 10.4 -> ArcGIS for Desktop Background Geoprocessing (64-bit).

Answer (score 8):

If you only have access to ArcGIS Desktop or Engine, you need to install the Background Geoprocessing for 64bit, check [Python scripting with 64-bit processing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/12/python-scripting-with-64-bit-processing/) at the ArcGIS Blog. If you have ArcGIS Server, the 64bit Python will be automatically installed.

A Help page on that: 
[What is 64-bit Background Geoprocessing?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Background_Geoprocessing_64_bit/002100000040000000/)

Comment: Following your link, I've only been able to find patches and installs for 10.1 and 10.2. I've tried those patches and installs and they give an error that says something to the effect of "These upgrades are for a different version". Do you know where I can find an upgrade patch for 10.4?